# Retrieve duration of video using FFprobe vs MP4Box

Tags: video, video-streaming, ffprobe, mp4box

I am using FFprobe and MP4Box for retrieving video streamlet information. I realised that there is a notable difference in the values returned.

The following command was used for FFprobe:

```
$ ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 1510579366733_9.ts
3.23334
```

However, using MP4Box to retrieve the duration for the same file returns a different value. The following command is used:

```sh
$ MP4Box -info 1510579366733_9.ts 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}'
2.826
```

*All my .ts files have are of ~3-second video segments so this should just return the number of seconds (instead of minutes or hours); not concerned about this right now.*

Which of the two values is supposedly more accurate?

Additionally, I also realised using `MP4Box -info` does not always retrieve the duration information of the ts file as well, whereas FFprobe has worked well with all my .ts files thus far.

Example:

```
$ MP4Box -info 1510579366733_10.ts
Import probing results for 1510579366733_10.ts:
File has 2 tracks
    Track 257 type: Audio (MP4A) - Program 1
    Track 258 type: Video (H264) - Program 1


$ MP4Box -info 1510579366733_9.ts
Import probing results for 1510579366733_9.ts:
File has 2 tracks
Duration: 2.826 s
    Track 257 type: Audio (MP4A) - Program 1
    Track 258 type: Video (H264) - Program 1
```

FYI the ffprobe (full) video information for `1510579366733_9.ts` is below:

```
ffprobe version N-86980-g62b7553 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/home/adminuser/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/adminuser/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/adminuser/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/adminuser/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 73.100 / 55. 73.100
  libavcodec     57.102.100 / 57.102.100
  libavformat    57. 76.100 / 57. 76.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 98.100 /  6. 98.100
  libswscale      4.  7.102 /  4.  7.102
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '1510579366733_9.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:03.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 447 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 137 kb/s
    Stream #0:1[0x102]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 426x240 [SAR 160:213 DAR 4:3], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
```

and for `1510579366733_10.ts`:

```
ffprobe version N-86980-g62b7553 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/home/adminuser/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/adminuser/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/adminuser/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/adminuser/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 73.100 / 55. 73.100
  libavcodec     57.102.100 / 57.102.100
  libavformat    57. 76.100 / 57. 76.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 98.100 /  6. 98.100
  libswscale      4.  7.102 /  4.  7.102
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '1510579366733_10.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:01.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 429 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s
    Stream #0:1[0x102]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 426x240 [SAR 160:213 DAR 4:3], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
```

Edit in response to [Mulvya's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47280227/retrieve-duration-of-video-using-ffprobe-vs-mp4box#comment81523482_47280227):
Using ffprobe with `stream=duration` is as follows: -

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 1510579366733_9.ts
3.178667
3.166667
3.178667
3.166667

$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 1510579366733_10.ts
1.066667
1.033333
1.066667
1.033333
```

Comment: What's the readout for `stream=duration` for audio and video streams?

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, I have updated the question and appended with the response to your question.

Comment: Remove `-select-streams` and run.

Comment: Hi @Mulvya, I have updated the response part of the question.

Comment: ffprobe will be more accurate.

Comment: GPAC maintainer here. Could you file an issue in [our tracker](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues) with a link to some samples so that we improve that together? Thanks